# emacs make frame switch buffer

Tags: emacs

I want to create a function in emacs that will create a new frame and then, in that new frame, fetch the list of buffers. I tried this:

```
(defun get-buffer-menu-in-new-frame (arg)
(make-frame)
(switch-to-buffer-other-frame ( list-buffers)))
```

I was working in init.el. I added this to call it:

```
(get-buffer-menu-in-new-frame)
```

Then I ran "eval-buffer". This seems to have worked: I got new frame, and it has the buffer list in it (I hope this result was not a coincidence.

But then I tried this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") 'get-buffer-menu-in-new-frame)
```

Then I hit the function4 key, but I got:

```
recursive-edit: Wrong type argument: commandp, get-buffer-menu-in-new-frame
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make your function into a command by using `interactive`.

```
(defun get-buffer-menu-in-new-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer-other-frame (list-buffers-noselect)))
```

I also removed arg that was not used.

Comment: Hmm, that helped, but I still have a problem. I added (interactive), then did eval-buffer. That allows me to hit the function4 button and get a result. But I get a strange result: a new frame appears but it is open to the init.el buffer where I was just working. Then another frame appears, or I switch frames, and the buffer list comes up. And I get: "pop-to-buffer: Wrong type argument: stringp, #<window 293 on *Buffer List*> ". I want the buffer list to appear in the new frame. What should I do?