# Getting bookmark-bmenu-list into a new frame

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks

Nicolas Dudebout helped me figure out the problem to my last function, which was how to get all the buffer menu to appear in a new frame. This was the final version:

```
(defun get-buffer-menu-in-new-frame ()
(interactive)
(switch-to-buffer-other-frame (list-buffers-noselect)))
```

This works great. [emacs make frame switch buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014036/emacs-make-frame-switch-buffer)

I wanted to also get the bookmark list in its own frame, and I thought this would easy:

```
(defun get-bookmarks-in-new-frame ()
(interactive)
(switch-to-buffer-other-frame (bookmark-bmenu-list)))
```

But when I do M-x get-bookmarks-in-new-frame I get this error:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp t)
  get-buffer(t)
  pop-to-buffer(t t nil)
  switch-to-buffer-other-frame(t)
  get-bookmarks-in-new-frame()
  eval((get-bookmarks-in-new-frame))

So I am thinking that bookmark-bmenu-list has a different return type than list-buffers-noselect, but I can not find this info. Any tips?